# Clearing C# Events after execution?

Tags: c#, events

Say I have the following code:

```
public event EventHandler DatabaseInitialized = delegate {};

//a intederminant amount of subscribers have subscribed to this event...


// sometime later fire the event, then create a new event handler...
DatabaseInitialized(null,EventArgs.Empty);

//THIS LINE IS IN QUESTION    
DatabaseInitialized = delegate {};
```

Will this clear out the subscribers, replacing it with new empty default? And, will the event notify all subscribers before they get cleared out? I.E. Is there a chance for a race condition?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it will clear it out. And because events fire syncronously in the same thread there shouldn't be race condition.

My advice: when in doubt, write a small test application and... well, test it.

*UPDATE:* I tested it before posting. (In response to minuses.)

Comment: Why would it clear it out?  I just adds another blank delegate to the event.

Comment: @CodingGorilla you're wrong. Test it and you'll see. Hint: `=` and `+=` is different operators.

Comment: It still would not clear it, at best it would remove all the others, still adding the new blank delegate.

Comment: @CodingGorilla: Yes, it does clear the existing subscribers. And using a new empty delegate (instead of null) is actually considered best practice since it avoids NullReferenceExceptions when firing the event.

Comment: @CodingGorilla: have _you_ tested it? Have you looked at the invocation list of the event before and after the "clear" operation? Did you notice that he's using _assignment_ and not `-=`?

Comment: @ChristofferLette Can you provide some documentation for that, I've not read that before and I'd like to read up on it (not that I don't believe you ;) ).

Comment: @JohnSaunders I did not test it (and my original response was prior to his update), and I did originally overlook the `=` vs. `-=`.  And I guess I took the word 'clear' a bit to literally.  I stand corrected.

Comment: @CodingGorilla well, strictly speaking, yes. But I think that's what OP meant. Also, technically speaking, you cannot "clear" an event -- the object containing the list of delegates is immutable. When you subscribe/unsubscribe to/from an event, new object is created and reference changed to point to a new object containg an updated list of delegates... In my opinion it's better to check if it's null before firing an event. That way we can 'clear' it by assigning it to null...

Comment: @Dmitry Agreed, I always check for null before firing an event, and like I said, I took the word 'clear' to literally I guess.

Comment: @Coding Gorilla - Can you support your assertion that that assigning an empty delegate to an event is the "best practices" way of clearing it? I would consider it as bad practice.

Comment: @Greg I wasn't arguing with his assertion, simply looking for some reading on the subject. TBH I've never needed to "clear" an event, I typically add a delegate, and remove it specifically when done with it.

Comment: @CodingGorilla I knew the words "best practice" would come back and haunt me... :) I know there's a question on the topic somewhere around here, but I can't find it atm. I will have to come back to you.

Comment: CodingGorilla - Sorry, my comment was supposed to be directed to @Christoffer Lette

Comment: You're right. I meant "clear out the events, and replace it with a new default event." Also it was actually faster for me to ask this, then it was to write the test program, so I do appreciate you taking the time to answer this.

Comment: @CodingGorilla I obviously overstated things in my previous comment. In trying to defend Dmitry's answer, I got carried away... If you use the empty delegate as an initializer for your event, you _could_ get away with not having to null-check before invoking. But not null-checking is just ridiculous! :-)

Comment: @Greg For the sake of discussion, I'm still interested in why you explicitly consider it bad practice, though.

Answer (score 0):

To `unsubscribe` from the event use `event-=delegate`, so you're sure that resource is free. Even if by official Microsoft documentation it's not necessary, in my own experience, especially on a large scale complex project, unnecessary events suscribers are source for memory leaks. So `unsubscribe` from them explicitly.

Comment: Unsubscribing delegates from events to prevent memory leaks would be like nulling references between objects. Are you sure that leaking was caused by events?

Comment: @Wiktor: exactly, by unsubscribing you release the pointer to your delegate and Yes, I'm absolutely sure that was one off the bottlenecks we resolve. As GC collects object which are not referenced by noone.

Comment: Unsubscribing is useful. Google for "weak event handlers", as you know event handler is a object with method info and a target on which the method is executed. Sometimes this wiring prevents GCing of the target object and of the source object as well. I have also upvoted this unswer since I agree with it.